# Using SpriteStage in EaselJS makes a Sprite's mask not work

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, easeljs

I'm doing animations with Sprites in EaselJS and due to performance issues I have to use the SpriteStage class to help with the perf. I'm also using alot of masks to make the sprites get clipped in certain parts.

Now when using a SpriteStage all my masks are not applied anymore. I'm thinking its because a SpriteStage do not support adding shapes to the childrens but I thought it could work since I'm not really adding it to the stage's children, merely applying it to a Sprite.

I used [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdpydqn6/) from another SO question, adding some code to show that masks are not working under SpriteStage.

```
var maskRect = new createjs.Graphics().drawRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
var shape = new createjs.Shape(maskRect);

var animation = new createjs.Sprite(ss);
animation.mask = shape; // Clip is applied
```

Is there any way to use masks under SpriteStage ? Or is there any way of getting the same effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpriteStage is meant for WebGL-based rendering, which currently has no support for Graphics/vector content at this time. This means that EaselJS Shapes, and vector masks are not supported.

You could probably create masked content, cache it, and then use the `.cacheCanvas` as your SpriteSheet. This is not ideal, and would be difficult to use with multiple sprites. You might be able to use SpriteSheetBuilder to generate a useful SpriteSheet. These are just suggestions, and nothing I have tested before.